# Где найти функции С++ для работы с Image?

Tags: c++

Есть такой сайт? Желательно на русском...

В языке php есть много функций для работы с изображением. А на С++ я таких функций не знаю.

Comment: Переформулируйте свой вопрос.

Comment: Что такое Image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С растровой графикой, имеется в виду?

Если да — есть, как минимум, три библиотеки — [GD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library), [ImageMagick](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) и [GraphicsMagick](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphicsMagick). Собственно, все три с примерами и дальнейшими ссылками что читать, упомянуты тут: http://habrahabr.ru/qa/5675/.

Уточняйте вопрос, если нужно что-то более конкретное.

У PHP есть биндинги для GD и ImageMagick, чаще всего [используется первое](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). API у libgd похож на тот что и в PHP, с минимальными различиями. Т.е., скажем, вместо `$img = imagecreate($width, $height)` будет `gdImagePtr img = gdImageCreate(width, height);`. [Сайт проекта libgd](http://libdg.org/), сейчас как-то скорее мертв, чем жив, но куча примеров есть в [директории examples в исходниках libgd](https://bitbucket.org/pierrejoye/gd-libgd/src/default/examples/).